# ImportError: Pandas requires version '3.0.7' or newer of 'openpyxl' (version '3.0.5' currently installed)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a strange problem which leads to the message in the title, leading to the error report below.

The fact is: I have (on Linux) Python 3.9.15, Pandas 1.5.2, [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) 3.0.10. I do not use venv, and for editing I use Wing, but I do not run scripts from it, only from the shell.

I looked over */usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/*, but I did not find any other version of openpyxl laying around. What's wrong? I even uninstalled and re-installed both pandas and openpyxl - no effect.

```
File "./elektreiba-00-02.py", line 140, in <module> main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./elektreiba-00-02.py", line 79, in main  df = pd.read_excel(infile, sheet_name=None)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 211, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 331, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 482, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 1695, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io, storage_options=storage_options)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 556, in __init__
    import_optional_dependency("openpyxl")
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py", line 171, in import_optional_dependency
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Pandas requires version '3.0.7' or newer of 'openpyxl' (version '3.0.5' currently installed)
```

Comment: I even fully removed py 3.9.15 and its libs and re-installed everything - the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out being a cache question. I don't have any idea what created a site-package cache under *~/./local/* and why the Python interpreter looked there at first.

Comment: I ran into this same issue after a fresh install of openpyxl from conda-forge.  Restarting the kernel resolved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try to un-install the openpyxl:

```
pip uninstall openpyxl
```

And reinstall it:

```
pip install openpyxl
```

This will do the work

[image]

Comment: See the solution below - it seems, I managed to install the package as the user, not root and than eventually created the problem

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75256184/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the same happened to me, pandas ask me for a openpyxl version that not exists yet ( 3.0.10 ).

> "ImportError: Pandas requires version '3.0.10' or newer of 'openpyxl'
> (version '3.0.9' currently installed). "

it seems i had installed pandas for python2 using `pip` command instead of `pip3`

if you are running python3 you should install:

```
sudo apt -y install python3-pandas
```

(and then remember to remove python2 version)

```
pip uninstall pandas
```

this worked for me. caution with this things.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
pip install openpyxl --upgrade --pre
```

Mine was asking for openpyxl version 3.1.0 when the default "conda install openpyxl" was installing openpyxl version 3.0.1.